# How to know and distinguish data that sended by tcp Connection?

Tags: vb.net

hi guys i'm making a client-server software and this is my first question
 i'd like to ask: how to distinguish data that sended by tcp Connection?

Well, my points are:
-we can determine data that sended by tcpconnection.
for example, we have 3 Listviews in our form
the point of the first listview is for *Biodata* of client.
the point of second listview is for *The value obtained from the clients
n the point of third listview is for *The picture obtained from the clients*

in this case we have 3 main points that must be processed.
in fact, we only have 1 connection in our system.

Well, here I'm confused..
how to determine that data we received is for the first listview or second listview or third listview?
remember, the data of third listview is a **picture** that we received from tcpconnection

How do we do that with 1 connection in our system?
do i have to make 3 connection to control third listviews?

Comment: You first should define and document your protocol. You could consider using HTTP (i.e. webservices), or something JSON based. And you certainly should consider coding in C, C++, Ocaml, ....

Comment: you could transmit TLV (type/length/value) structures over your connection: type would be 1,2 or 3, length would be the length of the data (size of biodata, size of picture,... depending on the type), and the value consists in the data bytes.

Comment: Isn't length/the value consists in the data bytes is always changing? can you explain me what TLV (type/length/value) especially "type" that you mean?

Comment: Do you really need to define your own protocol, or can you just use SOAP (Web Service or WCF Service)?  If you can use SOAP, your life will be much easier since those frameworks implement it so easily in Visual Studio.

Comment: in vb net, i use socket programming to make clients-server interaction. for now, i can only make mutual sending data between clienst-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With socket communication, both the client and the server must use the same agreed-upon protocol so that they can understand each other.  There are many standard protocols that have already been created, so for most tasks, creating your own protocol is unnecessary.  However, if you must, you can always define your own protocol.  The nature of your protocol will obviously depend completely on your specific needs, so it would be impossible to tell you what the protocol should be.  However, generally speaking, the first thing your protocol must define is how to know where each complete message begins and ends.  This is often accomplished by separating each message with a delimiter (e.g. new line, EOF, null).  As Francois recommended, you could alternatively specify the length of the message at the beginning of each message.  Within each message, you then will need a header section which, among other things, would specify the type (the format) of the data stored in the body of the message.

A simple implementation might be to send each message as a JSON or XML document.  Doing so makes it very easy to define and modify the format of the message.

However, unless you really need to, I would recommend using one of the built-in communication frameworks that are provided with .NET.  For simple tasks, often a simple asmx web service is sufficient.  For more complex tasks, often WCF is a good choice.  An asmx web service uses SOAP via HTTP via TCP/IP.  WCF uses SOAP, but the lower level connection is configurable so it doesn't have to use TCP/IP, but it can easily do so.

Comment: Steven,Socket communication, So the point of you, we can use delimiter or header section  to know what type of message is it? hmmm... what if the message is an image or a file? Can they mixed with our header message to define the type of our message?

Comment: If you're defining your own protocol, you can do whatever you want.  It's completely up to you.  Anything's possible.